# override default asp.net core cancelationtoken or change default timeout for requests

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous, asp.net-core-5.0, cancellation-token

In my asp.net core 5.0 app, I call an async method that might take some time to be processed.

```
 await someObject.LongRunningProcess(cancelationToken);
```

However, I want that method to be timeout after 5 seconds. I know that instead of "cancelationToken" passed by asp.net core action, I can use "CancellationTokenSource" :

```
var s_cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
s_cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    
await someObject.LongRunningProcess(s_cts );
```

Is it possible to use "**CancellationTokenSource**" as a default "Cancelation Token" policy for all asp.net core requests ? I mean override the one which is passed as a parameter of the action ?

Or is it possible to change the default timeout for all request in asp.net core 5.0 ?

[Update]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Customizing the `CancellationToken` passed to actions

You need to replace the default `CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider` that binds `HttpContext.RequestAborted` token to `CancellationToken` parameters of actions.

This involves creating a custom `IModelBinderProvider`. Then we can replace the default binding result with our own.

```cs
public class TimeoutCancellationTokenModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder? GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context?.Metadata.ModelType != typeof(CancellationToken))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var config = context.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<TimeoutOptions>>().Value;
        return new TimeoutCancellationTokenModelBinder(config);
    }

    private class TimeoutCancellationTokenModelBinder : CancellationTokenModelBinder, IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly TimeoutOptions _options;

        public TimeoutCancellationTokenModelBinder(TimeoutOptions options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        public new async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            await base.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
            if (bindingContext.Result.Model is CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                // combine the default token with a timeout
                var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                timeoutCts.CancelAfter(_options.Timeout);
                var combinedCts =
                    CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutCts.Token, cancellationToken);
                
                // We need to force boxing now, so we can insert the same reference to the boxed CancellationToken
                // in both the ValidationState and ModelBindingResult.
                //
                // DO NOT simplify this code by removing the cast.
                var model = (object)combinedCts.Token;
                bindingContext.ValidationState.Clear();
                bindingContext.ValidationState.Add(model, new ValidationStateEntry() { SuppressValidation = true });
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
        }
    }
}

class TimeoutOptions
{
    public int TimeoutSeconds { get; set; } = 30; // seconds
    public TimeSpan Timeout => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeoutSeconds);
}
```

Then add this provider to Mvc's default binder provider list. It needs to run before all others, so we insert it at the beginning.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinderProviders.RemoveType<CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider>();
        options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TimeoutCancellationTokenModelBinderProvider());
    });
    // remember to set the default timeout
    services.Configure<TimeoutOptions>(configuration => { configuration.TimeoutSeconds = 2; });
}
```

Now ASP.NET Core will run your binder whenever it sees a parameter of `CancellationToken` type, which combines `HttpContext.RequestAborted` token with our timeout token. The combined token is triggered whenever one of its component is cancelled (due to timeout or request abortion, whichever is cancelled first)

```cs
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken); // throws TaskCanceledException after 2 seconds
    return Ok("hey");
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/348b810d286fd2258aa763d6eda667a83ff972dc/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs
- https://abdus.dev/posts/aspnetcore-model-binding-json-query-params/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-model-binder-sample

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links and solution. I set the timeout to 3 seconds, run the API , BindModelAsync is called when I debug and code reaches the action, cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested = false, but despite that I have 5 seconds delay inside LongRunningProcess, it does not throw TaskCanceledException. Here you can see it https://github.com/persiandeveloper/custom-imediator-logic/tree/cancel_after

Comment: Does this throw? `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);`. Also use the latest code, I've made some updates.

Comment: It's working for me, and cancels the task.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtWAV.png

Comment: It works with the Delay inside Action but it does not worked when it is passed "Send", may you please look at https://github.com/persiandeveloper/custom-imediator-logic/blob/cancel_after/WebApp/Controllers/WeatherForecastController.cs ?

Comment: Well, if that works, then the cancellation token works. Mediator passes the token without changing it. https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/211dd8b244a9dd2d793a25d23884b697849632c2/src/MediatR/Mediator.cs#L27-L40. Problem is somewhere in your code.

Comment: You're not using the token: https://github.com/persiandeveloper/custom-imediator-logic/blob/e8c5f16a1d0d9e598b9f2ec2d9589d6f7d27ea68/ApplicationLogic/CreateUserCommandHandler.cs#L12. You must pass the token to `Task.Delay`

Answer (score 1):

One approach to solve this problem is wrapping that logic inside a class. Write a class that runs a task with a configurable timeout.

Then register it in DI, then use it anywhere you want to reuse the configuration.

```cs
public class TimeoutRunner
{
    private TimeoutRunnerOptions _options;

    public TimeoutRunner(IOptions<TimeoutRunnerOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public async Task<T> RunAsync<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> runnable,
                                     CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // cancel the task as soon as one of the tokens is set
        var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = timeoutCts.Token;
        if (cancellationToken != default)
        {
            timeoutCts.CancelAfter(_options.Timeout);
            var combinedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutCts.Token, cancellationToken);
            token = combinedCts.Token;
        }

        return await runnable(token);
    }
}

internal static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTimeoutRunner(this IServiceCollection services,
                                                      Action<TimeoutRunnerOptions> configure = null)
    {
        if (configure != null)
        {
            services.Configure<TimeoutRunnerOptions>(configure);
        }

        return services.AddTransient<TimeoutRunner>();
    }
}

public class TimeoutRunnerOptions
{
    public int TimeoutSeconds { get; set; } = 10;
    public TimeSpan Timeout => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeoutSeconds);
}
```

you'd then register this in Startup class,

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTimeoutRunner(options =>
    {
        options.TimeoutSeconds = 10;
    });
}
```

then consume it wherever you need that global option:

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private TimeoutRunner _timeoutRunner;

    public MyController(TimeoutRunner timeoutRunner)
    {
        _timeoutRunner = timeoutRunner;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _timeoutRunner.RunAsync(
            async (CancellationToken token) => {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), token);
            },
            cancellationToken
        );
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

### Running a task before every action dispatch

#### Method 1: Action filters

We can use action filters to run a task before/after every request.

```cs
public class ApiCallWithTimeeotActionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private TimeoutRunner _runner;

    public ApiCallWithTimeeotActionFilter(TimeoutRunner runner)
    {
        _runner = runner;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var result = await _runner.RunAsync(
            async (CancellationToken token) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), token);
                return 42;
            },
            default
        );
        await next();
    }
}
```

then to use it annotate a class with `[TypeFilter(typeof(MyAction))]`:

```cs
[TypeFilter(typeof(ApiCallWithTimeeotActionFilter))]
public class MyController : ControllerBase { /* ... */ }
```

#### Method 2: Middlewares

Another option is to use a middleware

```cs
class ApiCallTimeoutMiddleware
{
    private TimeoutRunner _runner;

    public ApiCallTimeoutMiddleware(TimeoutRunner runner)
    {
        _runner = runner;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // run a task before every request
        var result = await _runner.RunAsync(
            async (CancellationToken token) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), token);
                return 42;
            },
            default
        );
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

then attach the middleware in `Startup.Configure` method:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ApiCallTimeoutMiddleware>();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(e => e.MapControllers());
}
```

Comment: it it possible to have like a pipeline or middleware so it will be run for all requests ?

Comment: What do you mean by all requests? What does `someObject.LongRunningProcess` actually do? If that's an http request, there's a better way

Comment: I mean like pre-action method that calls the _timeoutRunner.RunAsync() and inside the RunAsync we call something like _requestDelegate, otherwise if I am going to use this helper only for this action, I can only pass  CancellationTokenSource to LongRunningProcess and I would not need the helper.

Comment: I updated the question with a flow of what I have in my mind.

Comment: Oh, You need an actionfilter for that, then inside it you can inject `TimeoutRunner` and then call the actual controller action

Comment: Thanks, I thought ActionFilters are deprecated since aspnet core and we only can use middlewares. By the way, is it possible to use middleware ? Or it is just for processing requestDelegate ?

Comment: No, they're not deprecated? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: You can use it with middleware too, let me update my answer

Comment: @BabakFakhriloo I updated my answer with both action filters & a middleware.

Comment: Should not  await next(context); in middleware be inside the RunAsync ? let me run it and I will back yo you to accept the answer

Comment: No, you can await it after the task completes. If you need to let the request run first, then you'd call if before calling `_runner.RunAsync()`

Comment: But the task is something that is called by action not outside of it. My goal is to wrap running of the action in a newer cancelation token policy. something like _runner.RunAsync(() => await next(new_cancelation_token));

Comment: I don't know how you'd do that without injecting something that runs your task in your classes. You have no (easy) control over the `CancellationToken` passed to an action, even if you do, [it only responds to request being cancelled](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs,30), not a timeout. So you need to combine that cancellation token yourself. Or you remove `CancellationTokenModelBinderProvider` from `MvcOptions` and replace it one that takes both request cancellation + timeout.

Comment: Oh now I understand you, you want to see if you can change the `CancellationToken` passed to controller actions.